# XPending cycle is making CPU 100%

Tags: c, message-queue, x11, xlib

Good day!

I have a little bit of troubles making a xlib project. Here is the structure of my project:

```
[ Init ]
[ Making some stuff ]
[ Creating a timer thread (see code below) ]
[ Main cycle (see code below) ]
```

When the user presses any button, I set the flag in the thread to true-like value and it starts to send CustomMessage to the window every n time.

```
while (warehouse.destroyflag != SML_DEAD)
{
    if (XPending(warehouse.display))
    {
        XNextEvent(warehouse.display, &event);
```

But there is a bit of problems here. **With the current realisation of the main cycle I have about 100% CPU load**. But when I remove the XPending line from the code, the load is about to be 0%. But in that case I don't have correct CustomMessage arriving from the another thread.

I have found the sample code of Xlib program and compiled it. It has the same problem, the CPU load is about 100%. Here is the sample:

http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=4897

Here is my thread's code:
http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=4898

And here is my cycle:
http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=4899

I read the GTK+ project code and found out that it has the very similar cycle, but I can't see that any of GTK+ applications have 100% CPU load because of that.

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: Q: Does it behave the same if you change to `if (XPending(warehouse.display) > 0) {...}`?

Comment: Yes, it stays the same

Comment: Just found out the solution. Edited the post, thank you!

Comment: @AlexTiger Show the solution as an answer Do not edit the question

Answer (score 2):

Alex, I've pulled your answer out of your question and posted it here for future reference.

Change the loop to:

```
while (warehouse.destroyflag != SML_DEAD)
{
    while (XNextEvent(warehouse.display, &event) >= 0)
    {
```

and the thread code to:

```
XLockDisplay(warehouse.display);
{
     XSendEvent(warehouse.display,
                event.xclient.window,
                0, NoEventMask, &event);
     XFlush(warehouse.display);
}
XUnlockDisplay(warehouse.display);
```